# Journal of Mathematical Physics Template

Tags: templates, journal-publishing

This is really a very strange question :D.
I am trying to find the LaTeX template for the Journal of Mathematical Physics. I found [this](https://www.sharelatex.com/templates/journals/american-institute-of-physics-aip) on sharelatex.com and I downloaded the RevTex4-1 file from aip.scitation.org/jmp/authors/manuscript. But if I compare the pdf files from sharelatex.com and from the samples folder they seem to be different to papers published in the Journal of Mathematical Physics (e.g. "[Exactly solvable Hermite, Laguerre, and Jacobi type quantum parametric oscillators](http://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.4972293)").

I hope someone can help me out :).

Comment: Did you try asking the Journal of Mathematical Physics?

Comment: @Skillmon: Not yet because I thought I was just too stupid to find the template :D. I will write them and post the answer here :).

Answer (score 3):

In my own experience this is rather common. The publisher begins with the source prepared by the authors, and then applies further changes to get the final version to be published. Fonts that appear in the printed version might be expensive, and the front page often includes a logo or other items that make the article easy to recognize.

You should think of the free template as a starting point: the TeX experts working with the publisher receive a standardized source, without strange macros or styles that the authors might have prepared at home ;-)